# How to generate Tiles with QuantumGIS or Mapnik

Tags: qgis, tiles, mapnik

I would like to know how to generate Map Tiles using QGis. I have heard that it is possible to create tiles using QGis, only, I don't know how to do that. Googling did not work for me since I am not really expertised with programming (Python etc.) and GIS.

However, I am experienced with accomplishing tasks that I am not experienced. So, if somebody can direct me to a tutorial/guide (detailed tutorial is preferred), I can manage to generate tiles.

I can also use Mapnik but as far as I understand, Mapnik does not have a GUI so I prefer QGis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a brandnew Qtile plugin, but only available for the latest Qgis Master version 1.9.0:

[Qtiles Announcement](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Announce-QTiles-plugin-td5024629.html)

Comment: Thank you Mr Andre,

does this "master versiyon 1.9.0" have an installer for windows or do you suggest that I use Linux instead of Windows? or maybe wait for a stable release?

Comment: You can use the OSGeo4W installer to install the dev build of QGIS

Comment: Great! I would love to try that... Thank you very much

Comment: I have successfully installed and generated tiles using Qtiles. Now, what I want to do is to use symbology for the tiles I generate. I could not find any css file or style options. Is there a way to change the symbology (icons etc.) and style?

Comment: I'm afraid there is little opportunity for that at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Andre, I will follow the announcement page. I hope they add this option soon

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://tilemill.com for a GUI on top of Mapnik.

Comment: Thank you Dane.. will have a look.. but basically, do you suggest Mapnik or QGis?

Comment: As a third opportunity, you can look at maperitive.net, which has improved a lot. Personally, I prefer the original Mapnik toolchain, with self-adapted rendering rules, including transparent overlay tiles. I use Qgis to copy and paste the data from various sources into the postgis database layer before rendering.

Comment: I have failed to import *.shp and *.tab files. Do I have to use only *.osm files with Maperetive?

Comment: I just had a course with TileMill and all I can say is, it rocks! great offer, thanks Dane